# Как xpath найти все элементы по классу и его подстроке?

Tags: html, xpath

Уважаемые пользователи stackoverflow, здравствуйте.
Нужен ваш совет.
Имеется следующая html-разметка документа:

```
<html>
<head> </head>

  <body>
    <div id="div1" class="div">Div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="div">Div2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Нужно написать xpath-запрос, который найдет все элементы, у которых класс = 'div' и текст содержит подстроку 'Div'. Как бы мне это сделать, пожалуйста, подскажите?

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так, наверное:

```
//*[@class = "div" and contains(./text(), "Div")]
```